# how to install dependencies for erlang

Tags: erlang

How to install erlang dependencies in ubuntu?

What is the recommended way to do this? What sort of tools are useful?

For example:

- nodejs I might use `nvm` and `npm`
- python i might use `venv` and `pip`
- c maybe something like `conan`

Is there an equivalent package manager for erlang? I saw something about `rebar`?

Or would it be more a process of tracking down each of the needed dependencies and compiling each, and placing them in `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, `rebar` looks pretty decent.

I see it can be as simple as:

0) `sudo apt-get install erlang-dev`

1) setup a rebar.config

2) `rebar get-deps`

See:

- http://www.rebar3.org/docs/configuration
- https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/blob/master/rebar.config.sample

Comment: as a note, `rebar3` and `rebar` are different projects, but you say `rebar` looks decent but link to `rebar3` documentation

Comment: good point. it is deprecated: https://github.com/rebar/rebar there is some history there?